# Mirth channel XML : how to read value from inside of an element

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

How to read a list of values from Mirth Channel XML's `<mapping>` element? I can use `msg` to read one value. But what if there are list of values? Example:

```
<patient>
    <name>names</name>
<patient>
```

If there is one value for`names` defined, then simply performing `<mapping>msg['patient']['name']</mapping>` will return the value. But how to get only values if the `names` return more than one name? How to iterate and display in the same XML? I am doing `Mirth` for the first time and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question in this way.. so you mean if you receive the XML in this fashion

```
<patient>
    <name>names</name>
    <name>name1</name>
</patient>
```

then how to iterate and fetch only 'name' tags value. If my understanding is correct then place the below code in your source transformer.

```
var nameLen = msg['name'].length();
for(i=0;i<nameLen;i++){
    // Your Mapping Logic
    logger.debug(msg['name'][i].toString());
}
```